# Determining the Storage type of an Image3D at runtime

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have a shader that takes an image3D as a uniform input, with the storage type hardcoded to be `r8`. However, the data that is passed to it by the main program is hopefully also going to be `r16f` and `r32f`. Is it possible to pass to the shader in some other format what type the data will be stored as at runtime? Currently I have it as `layout (r8, binding = 0) uniform image3D data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading format is hard-coded to the image, since the shader may have to do special work based on that format.

The most you could do is have several image variables, each with different bindings and formats. You'd bind the same image to all of them, and you pick which one to read from based on a `uniform`.

Answer (score 1):

So `data` will be one of several types (r8, r16, r32). It seems you would like to have a C++ish overloaded (or even with template) way to pass and read an uniform. No. GLSL is not C++, not even C.

[GLSL4.5 spec 4.4.6.2](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) says:

> Only one format qualifier may be specified for any image variable
>   declaration

So `data` can be assigned a format once, at compiling time.

You can have several uniforms with different formats and bindings. Or several shaders perhaps with a shared subroutine.